# Bootstrap navbar collapse opens in the wrong place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Navbar collapsed menu fits perfectly to the navbar in Safari browser and occupy full width of the viewport. However, in other browsers collapsed navbar is getting smaller and sticks to the very top of the page. Looks like it is not connected to the navbar itself and drops down from another reference point. Is this a browser prefix issue or something entirely wrong with my bootstrap structure?[image: navbar collapse doesn't fit]

```css
   .navbar {
      height: 60px; 
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border-bottom: .1px solid black; 
      background: #ffffff;
   }

   .navbar-nav { 
      margin-top: 1.5em; 
   }

   .navBut {
      margin: 20px 0;
   }

   .navButBut {
      border: 1px solid red;
   }

   .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: black !important;
      color: snow;
      height: 30px;
      width: 45px;
      padding: 2px 5px 0;
      margin: 15px 8% 15px 0;
   }

   .navbar-toggle:hover {
      background-color: transparent !important;
   }

   .dropbut {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: black;
   }

   .fa-korvue {
      color: #962715; 
      font-size: 3.5em; 
      line-height: -45%; 
      float: left; 
      margin: 5px 8% 0 12%;
   }

   .link_icon, .link_icon:link, .link_icon:visited, .link_icon:active {
      color: #1e1e20;
      padding: 0;
      margin-right: 20px;
      font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: transparent;
   }

    #collapse_menu {
      margin-top: 1.2em;
    }

    #collapse_menu li a {
      padding: 3px 8px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      border-radius: 3px;
   }

   #collapse_menu li a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
   }

   .hidden-xs {
      margin-right: 18px;
   }

   #phone_handset {
      color: black;
      font-size: 1.7em; 
      vertical-align: 10%;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: 0;
      transition: 1s;
   }

   #phone_num {
      display: inline;
      margin-right: 4em; 
      vertical-align: 20%; 
      font-size: 1.3em;
   }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="fa fa-th dropbut"></span>                      
        </button>

        <i class="fab fa-korvue"></i>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

          <ul id="collapse_menu" class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="1" href="#top_page_scroll">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="2" href="#about_me_scroll">Обо мне</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="3" href="#portfolio_scroll">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="4" href="#pricing_scroll">Цены</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="5" href="#contact_me_scroll">Регистрация</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right vertical-align">
             <a id="phone_handset" class="fas fa-phone-volume hidden-xs" href="#"></a>
             <a id="phone_num" class="link_icon hidden-xs" href="#">110-223-456-78</a>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: I'm using Chrome and viewing the snippet and aside from the white on white color scheme it looks like it's working.  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @fnostro I want collapsed navbar to fit the whole width of the screen. Hiwever, now, as you can see from the attached screenshot, it dorsn’t fit and sliding from the very top of the page for some reason...

Comment: I've removed all your css to get a fresh perspective on your base navs.  In the Chrome browser it's behaving normally. So it seems your css is altering some expected behaviors and possibly breaking cross-browser compatibilities

Comment: @fnostro wow, I totally forgot to disable css to check if that was the problem. Thanks. Hope I can fix it.

Comment: fwiw: you are also missing the `<div class="navbar-header">` wrapper around your version of the "hamburger" and missing a `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>` wrapper around your `<i class="fab fa-korvue"></i>`

Comment: @fnostro Hmmm, I thought its safe to omit it...

Comment: May well be, but general rule of thumb is get it working before you start removing pieces of the framework. Bootstrap 3 relies heavily on the child selector (` > `) in a lot of it's styling. Removing a parent container may have adverse affects.

Comment: @fnostro thanx again. I started to learn bs only recently and had no clue that the framework structure is so significant. It was working in Safari no probs and I thought its probably some sort of cross-browser prefix issues. Now I know how deep is the rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue. If you wrap navbar-toggle with `<div class=“navbar-header”>` then everything starts to work as expected. Now collapsed navbar occupies full width and sits in the right place. Thank @fnostro for the valuable tips.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="fa fa-th dropbut"></span>                      
        </button>
        <i class="fab fa-korvue"></i>
     </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

          <ul id="collapse_menu" class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="1" href="#top_page_scroll">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="2" href="#about_me_scroll">Обо мне</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="3" href="#portfolio_scroll">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="4" href="#pricing_scroll">Цены</a></li>
            <li><a class="link_icon scroll" name="5" href="#contact_me_scroll">Регистрация</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right vertical-align">
             <a id="phone_handset" class="fas fa-phone-volume hidden-xs" href="#"></a>
             <a id="phone_num" class="link_icon hidden-xs" href="#">110-223-456-78</a>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```